# unable in creating thumb IMAGE IS BLACK

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

Am uploading **Multiple image from single input** and create thumb form all uploaded image on fly But when i run code i get **only black image** but orginal image is same as uploaded

```
    $orig_directory = "$desired_dir";    //Full image folder
$thumb_directory =  "thumb/";    //Thumbnail folder

/* Opening the thumbnail directory and looping through all the thumbs: */
$dir_handle = @opendir($orig_directory); //Open Full image dirrectory
if ($dir_handle > 1){ //Check to make sure the folder opened

$allowed_types=array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
$file_type=array();
$ext='';
$title='';
$i=0;

while ($file_name = @readdir($dir_handle)) {
    /* Skipping the system files: */
    if($file_name=='.' || $file_name == '..') continue;

    $file_type = explode('.',$file_name);    //This gets the file name of the images
    $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_type));

    /* Using the file name (withouth the extension) as a image title: */
    $title = implode('.',$file_type);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);

    /* If the file extension is allowed: */
    if(in_array($ext,$allowed_types)) {

        /* If you would like to inpute images into a database, do your mysql query here */

        /* The code past here is the code at the start of the tutorial */
        /* Outputting each image: */

        $nw = 100;
        $nh = 100;
        $source = "$desired_dir{$file_name}";
        $stype = explode(".", $source);
        $stype = $stype[count($stype)-1];
        $dest = "thumb/{$file_name}";

        $size = getimagesize($source);
        $w = $size[0];
        $h = $size[1];

        switch($stype) {
            case 'gif':
                $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                break;
            case 'jpg': 
                $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                break;
            case 'png':
                $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                break;
        }

        $dimg = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
        $wm = $w/$nw;
        $hm = $h/$nw;
        $h_height = $nh/2;
        $w_height = $nw/2;

        if($w> $h) {
            $adjusted_width = $w / $hm;
            $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
            $int_width = $w / $hm;
            imagecopyresampled($dimg,$simg,-$int_width,0,0,0,$adjusted_width,$nh,$w,$h);
        } else {
            imagecopyresampled($dimg,$simg,0,0,0,0,$nw,$nh,$w,$h);
        }
            imagejpeg($dimg,$dest,100);
        }
}

/* Closing the directory */
@closedir($dir_handle);

}
?>
```

i get only black image when i run code i don't know what happens **i get ERROR in the above the thumb is black**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <pre><?
            print_r($_FILES); //SHOW THE ARRAY

            foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
                if (!$file['error']) {
                    //PROCESS THE FILE HERE
                    echo $file['name'];
                }
            }
        ?></pre>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var fd = new FormData(); 
            $(document).ready(function() {

                //submit dragdropped by ajax
                $("#dropsubmit").on("click", function(e) {
                     $.ajax({           
                        data: fd,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data){
                            //FILES POSTED OK! REDIRECT
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                      });
                })

                var dropzone = $("#dropzone");
                dropzone.on('dragenter', function (e) {
                    $(this).css('background', 'lightgreen');
                });

                //dropped files, store as formdata
                dropzone.on('dragover', stopPropagate);
                dropzone.on('drop', function (e) {
                    stopPropagate(e)
                    $(this).css('background', 'white');
                     var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

                     for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)  {
                        preview(files[i])
                        fd.append('file' + (i + 1), files[i]);
                        if (i >= 5) continue
                     }

                });
                function stopPropagate(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                } 


                if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
                    $("input[type=file]").on("change", function(e) {
                        preview(e.target.files[0])
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
                }

                function preview(item) {
                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                        var file = e.target;
                        $("<img></img>", {
                            class: "imageThumb",
                            src: file.result,
                            title: file.name,
                        }).appendTo("#images");
                    });
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(item);
                }
            });
        </script>

        <div id="dropzone" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px dashed gray;padding:10px">Drag & Drop Files Here</div>
        <input type="button" id="dropsubmit" value="Submit dropped files" />
        <hr>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input id="file1" name="file1" type="file"/><br>
            <input id="file2" name="file2" type="file"/><br>
            <input id="file3" name="file3" type="file"/><br>
            <input id="file4" name="file3" type="file"/><br>
            <input id="file5" name="file3" type="file"/><br>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload files" />
        </form><div id="images"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```